# Find when audio track starts in merged audio file

Tags: command-line, audio, ffmpeg, mp3

Merged.mp3 = Intro.mp3 || Mid.mp3 (where || means concatenation)

I have Mid.mp3 and Merged.mp3. I'd like to know when exactly Intro.mp3 ends and Mid.mp3 starts in Merged.mp3. I need to do this programmatically (preferably using FFMPEG) since I have tons of files. What would be the best way to approach this?

What comes to my mind is exporting these to PCM and writing something that increases the offset and continuously XORs those and prints the offset that gave the minimum square-sum but that seems overkill. Could you please suggest a less exciting, standard approach?

Comment: Might solve my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49583591/6557621

Answer (score 0):

I ended up coding what I described, with subtraction instead of XOR and chi-squared stats instead of square summing (the difference is in dividision).

If you encounter the same problem [DTW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49409440/how-to-find-what-time-a-part-of-audio-starts-and-ends-in-another-audio/49583591#49583591) might work for you.